# Cannot use flashvars autostart true YouTube api

Tags: youtube-api, swfobject

I have the following Javascript code but the video does not autostarted, why?

```
var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always" };
    var atts = { id: "myvideoplayer"};
    var flashvars = {autostart: true};

    swfobject.embedSWF(

        "http://www.youtube.com/v/MHRj8BYm240?enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer&version=3", "ytplayer", "425", "365", "8", null, flashvars, params, atts);

    function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
    ytplayer = document.getElementById("myvideoplayer");
    //ytplayer.playVideo();
}
```

Ok, maybe I'm supposed to to use `playVideo()` as soon as the YouTube player is ready, but whatabout other flashvars e.g. `displayclick` and `click`?

Answer (score 0):

Add &autoplay=1 to video URL and it should work